# I am trying to install the mido module on python to work with some midi. However, it displays an error message. What should i do?

Tags: python, module

[this messsage pops up in the kernel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neiwu.png)

I tried to install the module using pip install however it displays that the "pip" module isn't available. I am writing a code to make a program connecting my DAW MIDI to python

Comment: Please include the text of the error message in your question, formatted as a code sample. Do not use pictures of text or *links* to pictures of text.